# Euler diagram generator without having to download stuff

Tags: web-apps, diagram

I'm fascinated by these things and I want to make my own. Problem is, Chromebooks don't like `.jar` files. Or pretty much *any* files. So is there a simple online generator where I can type in, e.g., "all X are Y; not all Z are X; all Z are Y", and get back its diagram?

*(Sorry if this question isn't the best... first-timer)*